# Почему я могу присвоить массив объекту?

Tags: java, массивы, объекты, компиляция

Почему в строке с комментарием не дает ошибку компиляции? 
Пробовал с другими ссылочными типами - там все нормально, ошибка компиляции, а в случае с типом Object ничего подобного...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[]{1,0,2};
        Object p = nums; //почему данная строка компилируется???
        int[] two = (int[])p;
        System.out.println(10/two[2]);
    }
```

Что здесь такого элементарного, что я не вижу настолько, что в прям удивлен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилируется, потому что [массив - это объект](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1).

> An object (§4.3.1) is a dynamically created instance of a class type or a dynamically created array. All objects, including arrays, support the methods of class Object (§4.3.2).

Comment: Ну то что, обьект это я и так вижу, ключевое слово new на то подтверждение. Мне только напрягло то, что я ожидал увидеть хотя бы [] так как вроде массив [] предполагает... хотя пробовал с []  ссылку Object - появился ошибка компиляции... возможно неправильно и вообще не с туда зашел, просто глаза мои привыкли видеть в объявлении ссылки  [] как признак что будем присваивать обьект массива.

Comment: ладно, на уровне аксиоматики пожалуй можно данный результат компиляции запомнить, но вопрос пока оставляю открытым.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan Если добавить [] к Object, то получается ссылка на массив объектов, что может быть массивом массивов.

Comment: просто очень интересно, как удается классу Object не конфликтовать присвоением массива, в то время как другие ссылочные переменные ( ссылки) сразу отмечаются как несовместимые.  Есть один способ легко понять это. Распознавание класса Object как логический совместимого  типа ссылки для присвоения обьекта массива - закодирован/внедрен прямо в компиляторе.  Я правильно мыслю? если да, и нечего добавить - значит вопрос уже смогу закрыть уверенно зная, что ответ на свой вопрос я получил.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan "в том время как другие ссылочные переменные ( ссылки) сразу отмечаются как несовместимые" Я не уверен, что понял эту мысль. Почитайте про явные и неявные преобразования в java, они же расширяющие и сужающие преобразования.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan В java существуют явные и неявные преобразования. Вторые (неявные) выполнятся автоматически, первые же необходимо указывать явно. Автоматически выполняются расширяющие преобразования - от более конкретного типа к более общему. т.е., например, `Object o; Number n; Integer i = 0; o = n = i;` нормально, т.к, намбер является объектом, а интежер намбером. Точно также работает и в случае с массивом, потому что массив это объект, как и намбер.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan Явно указывать преобразование необходимо в случае с сужающим преобразованием (от более общего к более конкретному), например, от Number к Integer, будучи уверенным, что за ссылкой на Number скрывается именно Integer, иначе можно нарваться на ошибку `i = (Integer) n`.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan Ну так прям совсем любой другой ссылочный тип не является массивом... Это как животные: кошки и собаки. И кошки, и собаки наследуются от животных и являются животными. Но кошки не являются собаками, как и собаки кошками, их наследование от животных происходит параллельно друг другу. Так и тут. Массив, как и другие ссылочные типы, является объектом, объект для них общий прародитель, но они не являются друг другом. Надеюсь так понятней...

Comment: Ладно на этом контексте легче понять и запомнить.. думаю уже нет смысла тянуть.. пожалуй можно считать вопрос закрытым.