# Какие из типов данных ссылочного типа (не примитив)?

Tags: java, массивы, типы

Вопрос из одного теста, который навел меня на мысль, что с массивом дела обстоят куда сложнее чем мне казалось ранее:

> Which of the following is a reference variable (and not a primitive?) (Choose all that apply)
>
> - A) int[] ints;
> - B) long[] longs;
> - C) String[] strings;
> - D) Object[] objects;
> - E) None of the above.

первые два варианта я бы не выбрал, предположил, что ответами могут быть варианты C и D, но оказалось, что это E. Теперь у меня кружатся две мысли:

- либо автор теста ошибся,
- либо утверждение, что "типы бывают два вида: примитивные и ссылочные" не 
  верный, так как оказывается, есть еще и третий вид переменных.

Что скажете?

Comment: Любой массив это ссылочный тип данных. Ошибки в тесте нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017243/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83

Comment: В рамках самого тесте нет, я не говорил что ошибка в прям в тесте, я сделал акцент на странную отметку в роли правильного ответа, который и был причиной моего заблуждения. Со стороны проверяющего был отмечен вариант Е. Выводы написанные ниже примера теста в моем вопросе - сделаны именно на основе ответа со стороны проверяющего теста. (Я уже на основе ответов ниже, понял, что тот проверяющий опять таки отметил неправильный ответ и увел мои мысли не туда.) Думаю я уже полостью разобрался в данном вопросе, если с вашей точки зрения это не так, я буду рад узнать в чем моя ошибка понимания.

Comment: Перечитал мое написанное в вопросе, да, пожалуй вполне можно было предположить, что я имел ввиду что именно в содержимом тесте я заметил ошибку. Пардон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2

> A variable of array type holds a reference to an object.

то есть

> Переменная типа массив содержит ссылку на объект.

Ответ:

`A, B, C, D`

Comment: Спасибо, что сразу два мифа сняли с кандидатуры.

Comment: первый миф 1) вариант Е и якобы правильность автора теста,  и 2) якобы не принадлежность массивов примитивного типа к понятию "ссылочный тип". Теперь известно, что примитивный тип + [] == ссылочный тип. Если что то все таки не так я сформулировал или понял - скажите.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что правильный ответ  С) так как, первые 2 варианта примитивные, 4 не совсем переменная, 5 сразу отпадает и остается 3.
Скорее всего 3 вариант

Comment: я тоже так думаю, но интересно было то, что в тесте у меня отмечено что правильным почему то является именно вариант Е. Собственно из за такой странности пришлось опубликовать тут эту странность в виде вопроса.

Comment: скорее всего ошибка, потому что `string` это точно сылочный тип

Comment: Ну да, это я знаю, тут просто подумал, вдруг каким то чудным образом [] рядом со String меняет принадлежность типа... иначе другого логичного оправдания я не нахожу для такого странного ответа отмеченного у меня в тесте.